# Retrofit Authorization is not working with variable token

Tags: android, authorization, retrofit, token, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to add Token to my Header using Retrofit as below:

```
public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstanceForAPIGateway(String token) {
    Log.e("RetrofitClient", "Token: " + token);

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(chain -> {
        Request newRequest  = chain.request().newBuilder()
                .addHeader("Authorization", token) //Token passed from view controller
                .build();
        return chain.proceed(newRequest);
    }).build();

    if (retrofit_api == null) {
        retrofit_api = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(client)
                .baseUrl(API_GATEWAY_BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit_api;
}
```

I am getting 403 error however if I hard code token with existing token string as below, it is working as expected.

.addHeader("Authorization", "eyJW********") // Hard coded the token

Please help what should I do?

Comment: you may need the scheme ? for example Basic, Bearer... Any more informations about where you're using that would be useful

Comment: `retrofit_api` is only conditionally created with the okhttp client that sets the token - any chance that you've already set up `retrofit_api` earlier?

Comment: @laalto - No I haven't set retrofit_api before this call.

Comment: @Ahmed - AWS Cognito is expecting token without any prefix. Not sure what is the issue as when I am passing the token string (hard code not the token variable) it is working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the token type on the header, change your code as below

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(chain -> {
    Request newRequest  = chain.request().newBuilder()
            .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer $token") //Token passed from view controller
            .build();
    return chain.proceed(newRequest);
}).build();
```

without the token type retrofit will not be able to identify the header.

Comment: AWS Cognito is expecting token without any prefix. However when I am trying "$token" getting 401 error. Not sure what is the issue as when I am passing the token string (hard code) it is working.